# Non-Gaussian random field generation

Tags: random-process

I would like to generate a height field that has a user specified distribution
of slopes. Generating a random field with Gaussian slope distribution
is easy.

Is there a relatively simple way to generate non-Gaussian random fields
in Mathematica?

Comment: Please be a bit more specific. Height field over what? The real line or the plane? Do you know about `RandomVariate`?

Comment: Yes, height field in a plane. Of course you can generate heights that are distributed with whatever distribution you want. But I do not care about distribution of heights, but distribution of slopes. So, I want to generate a height field H(x, y) that has slopes (dH/dx, dH/dy) distributed based on specified distribution.